# Добавление файлов в VLAD-PC: VLAD

Tags: windows, сеть, mediaplayer, внешние-устройства, устройства

Есть структура устройств

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

После открытия выделенного VLAD-PC: VLAD появилось окно

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как добавить файлы к VLAD-PC: VLAD->Видео ? (не только с помощью команд Windows Media Player, возможно через папку VLAD-PC: VLAD, но как называется эта папка я не знаю). Мне это необходимо для просмотра видео на телевизоре, который имеет доступ VLAD-PC: VLAD .

Comment: Не думаю, что вопрос по тематике сайта

Comment: Гугли `dlna` и как это реализовано в windows media player.